# To prove that every bounded function holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus K$ is constant

Tags: several-complex-variables

I have to prove that every bounded function holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus K$ is constant, where $K$ is 
$(a)$ a ball 
$(b)$ a complex line 
$(c)$ an arbitrary analytic subset

Now, I think the idea here is to show that the holomorphic function can be extended to all of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and thereafter using Liouville's theorem  to show the bounded function as constant, but I am kind of lost on how to proceed to do that. Can I get some help?

Comment: Try and assume it isn't bounded, and then look at the coefficients (using the fact it is analytic, it has a Taylor series) and use Liouville's theorem to show they must all be $0$ (except for $a_0$).

Comment: I don't think I get the strategy completely, I'm not sure how I can sure that the coefficients are $0$. Can you show me an example of this calculation?

Comment: For a ball centered at $z_0$, think of $\frac1{z-z_0}$.

Answer (score 0):

(i) If $K$ is a ball, we may use Hartogs' extension theorem.

(ii) Note a complex line is also an analytic subset. We may just consider the case $K$ is an analytic subset. But then
$\mathbb{C}^2\setminus K$ is connected, and every locally bounded holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus K$
can be extended to $\mathbb{C}^2.$ See Demailly, complex analytic and differential geometry, P91 Remark 4.2.